# Можно ли писать прямиком в syslog?

Tags: linux, c, логирование

Можно ли делать запись прямиком в `/dev/log` как в `/dev/stdout`? Например так:

```
echo test > /dev/log
```

У меня вылетает ошибка:

> bash: log: Нет такого устройства или адреса.

Если это вообще возможно, то что я делаю не так?

Comment: [logger](https://linux.die.net/man/1/logger)

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. А если такая проблема: я цепляю к своей программе библиотеку, которая внутри считывает переменную окружения(путь до файла) и пишет в него. Мне надо писать в syslog внутри библиотеки  используется write(), переписывать библиотеку не вариант.

Comment: https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imfile.html

Comment: Обычно `/dev/log` это симлинк на `srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Oct  8 23:26 /run/systemd/journal/dev-log=`.  Команда `file /run/systemd/journal/dev-log=` сообщает, что на самом деле это сокет, а `fuser` вместе с `ps` покажут, что данный сокет слушает демон `/lib/systemd/systemd-journald`.  Т.о.  для записи сообщений вам нужно использовать, например, `echo "..." | netcat -Uu /dev/log`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Мне надо писать в syslog внутри библиотеки используется write()

Это кто Вас надоумил так делать?! :-) Два момента. Первый:

```
$ ls -l /var/log/sys*
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   20148 окт  8 09:05 /var/log/syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  380325 окт  8 08:22 /var/log/syslog.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   46102 окт  7 08:25 /var/log/syslog.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   51345 окт  4 08:26 /var/log/syslog.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  212595 окт  3 08:47 /var/log/syslog.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   71915 окт  1 08:28 /var/log/syslog.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   54724 сен 30 08:23 /var/log/syslog.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   82350 сен 27 08:29 /var/log/syslog.7.gz
```

Понимаете, что это означает? То, что **писать** в этот файл может **только** демон *syslog*, а читать - только он и члены группы *adm*. Так что, записать с помощью *write()* у Вас не получится никак. Без  прав *root*.

Второе. Для того, что бы пользоваться услугами демона *syslog* существует набор стандартных системных функций:

```
void openlog(const char *ident, int option, int facility);
void syslog(int priority, const char *format, ...);
void closelog(void);
```

А тех программистов, которые пишут свои собственные "лог-файлы" с использованием *write()* я считаю не очень уными людьми. Ведь достаточно просто выполнить команду

```
man 3 syslog
```

и можно посмотреть готовое решение проблемы. Особенно не люблю программёров, которые сообщения об ошибках и отладочные сообщения выдают с помощью *printf()*. Когда в службу поддержки обращается клиент и говорит, что у него ВЧЕРА было что-то непонятное с программой, то эти сообщения в ЕГО stderr исчезнувшие ещё вчера - представляют просто таки "бесценную" помощь для программиста сопровождения.

На самый крайний случай, если заменить *write()* на *syslog()* нет никакой возможности, рекомендую попробовать такой метод:

Пишем программу, которая:

1. С помощью *inotify* (man 7 inotify) устанавливает слежение за файлом, в который исходная программа пишет сообщения.
2. Получив уведомление о записи в этот файл, программа считывает добавленный кусок текста. Это можно сделать, зная исходную и новую длину файла.
3. Записывает полученный текст в системный лог, используя *syslog()*.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Linux команда `logger` даёт удобный способ писать в системный лог `/var/log/syslog` из командной строки, из скриптов или других файлов

```
$ logger comment to be added to log
$ tail -1 /vvar/log/syslog
May 21 18:02:16 butterfly shs: comment to be added to log
```

---

```
$ logger `who`
$ tail -1 /var/log/syslog

May 21 18:02:43 butterfly shs: shs pts/0 2018-05-21 15:57 (192.168.0.15)
```

---

```
$cat msg
Backups to off-site facility will run this coming weekend. System availability will not be affected.
```

---

```
$ logger -f msg
$ tail -2 /var/log/syslog

May 21 18:06:01 butterfly shs: Backups to off-site facility will run this coming weekend.
May 21 18:06:01 butterfly shs: System availability will not be affected
```

---

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что [вопросы и ответы на сайте должны быть на русском языке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8410/213987).

Comment: А ещё код в них должен быть отформатирован.

Comment: У меня системный лог хранится в `/var/log/messages`, а не в `/var/log/syslog`. `lsb_release -a`: `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)`.